# jQuery Works in Fiddle and at the Bottom of Page, but Not With Dynamic (jQuery Generated) Content

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery that works perfectly in a fiddle and at the bottom of my page. jQuery is included in the head of the project. Within this project, I am using a jQuery RSS Plugin that generates dynamic content from a feed and structures the output within a string (entryTemplate):

```
 <script>
var j=jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function() { 
      jQuery(function($) {
        j("#bird-feedsz")
            .rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/patheos/Ukoy", {
             layoutTemplate: '{entries}',
             entryTemplate: '<div class="view span12"><div class="view-back"><a class="feedLink" href="#">Go</a><div class="feedBody">{body}</div></div><div class="front"><div class="date circle">{prettyDate}</div><div class="title">{title}<br>{author}</div></div></div>',
             tokens: {
                prettyDate: function(entry, tokens) {
                return moment(tokens.date).format("DD MMM")
                          }
                      }
                    });
                  });
                });
 </script>
```

I want to run a jQuery click function on content from that string.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".feedLink").click(function (e) {
     $(".feedBody").removeClass("active");
      $("div.deck").empty();
     $(e.target).focus().next(".feedBody").addClass("active");
     $(".active").clone().appendTo("div .deck");

    e.preventDefault();
   });
});
</script>
```

Below is the string. If I take it out of the script and place it as pure html at the bottom of my document it works!

```
 <div class="view span12"><div class="view-back"><a class="feedLink" href="#">Go</a><div class="feedBody">{body}</div></div><div class="front"><div class="date circle">{prettyDate}</div><div class="title">{title}<br>{author}</div></div></div>
```

But once generated by the plugin, my script breaks. I think the issue is that its buried too deep and can't find the class "deck," but I am not sure.  Here is the rest of my html structure:

```
    <div class="span2">

    </div>



    <div id="jp-container" class="jp-container span4">



       <div id="bird-feeds"></div>
        <div id="bird-feedsz"></div>


    </div>
```

```
    <div class="span6"> 

        <div class="row-fluid">

          <div class="span12"> <img class="banner" src="/assets/banner.png"/></div>


        </div>


        <div class="deck row-fluid">
            <h5>Latest News</h5>
               <div class="span2">
              <img class="circle" src="/assets/scotmcknight.png"/>
              </div>
            <div class="span10 intro">
              <p>Welcome to iNOTEISH. Discover. Follow. Inspire.<p>
            </div>
            <div class="twitterhack span12">
              <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/iNOTEISH"  data-chrome="transparent noborders nofooter noloadmore noheader" data-widget-id="334372455831453698"></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
              <img class="circle" src="/assets/scotmcknight.png"/>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
              <img class="circle" src="/assets/scotmcknight.png"/>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
              <img class="circle" src="/assets/scotmcknight.png"/>
            </div>

             <div id="mydiv3" style="text-align:center; padding: 15px; margin: 15px;" class="span12"></div>

        </div>

      </div>
```

```
  </div>
```

HELP PLEASE! Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zF65u/ and the plugin: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

Comment: Did you mean for the space before the function declaration in this line (second script you entered). Is it actually a comma?
`$(".feedLink").on("click", ".contents" function (e) {`

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong bit there. I was trying to fix things by running an on function instead, but never had any luck. The edited code above is the working code in the fiddle and when not in the jQuery string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this a case of the `.feedlink` element not being present on doc ready?  Maybe just change this line:

```
$(".feedLink").click(function (e) {
```

to this:

```
$(".feedLink").on('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: swatkins -tried that too. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: swatkins. I think you are on the correct track though. <script>

$(".feedLink").on('click', function () {

         alert("Link Does Work");
      
        
}); doesnt return anything either.